# passing a pointer parameter to a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters

I have seen and written functions that pass parameters in reference to update objects because either I needed the return code or I needed to change more than one variable in one function.

Now I saw a code written like below, and I’m having a hard time understanding how/why the bool variable (at the bottom of the code snippet) is being passed as a reference while the function signature is pointer, and assign the value back to it using *?

How is this working? May I ask for an explanation? I tried to google pointer parameter and etc but couldn’t find the answer to this kind of question.

```
// header file 
int fetchResult(bool* result_p, const Info& info, int section)

// implementation
int fetchResult(bool* result_p, const Info& info, int section)
{
…
*result_p = resultValue;
…
return 0;
}

// usage 
bool result = false;
fetchResult(&result, info, section);
```

Comment: Why don't you try calling the function the way you think it should be called (no `&`), and look carefully at the compiler error you get?  That's a more robust way to learn than asking strangers.

Comment: It looks like `result` is being used as a return parameter. `fetchResult` assigns some value to it. Maybe. Sometimes? It's hard to tell without the rest of the method.

Comment: Oh wait. Do you think `&result` is a reference? It's not. The `&` is very overloaded in C++. It's used for several things, and you'd get confused if you don't know what they all are. `&result` has type `bool*`. It means "the address of `result`".

Comment: `&` has three different meanings in C++, a reference declaration is just one of them. This specific usage of `&`, you zeroed in on, is not a reference declaration. Just like the usage of `*` here is not multiplication. Welcome to C++.

Answer (score -1):

Passing a function parameter as a reference or as a pointer both allow the function to write back into the parameter (when not `const` ofc), and allow for more then one return value.
Both calls handle pretty much the same, with the one difference being that a reference cannot be null, but a pointer can be. So using call by reference is usually preferred, as it saves one check for null.

Passing by pointer is sometimes used for optional parameters, as the caller can just pass a `nullptr` for a not required additional return value.

When passing by const-ref (as in you example), the parameter is not intended as a return value, but as an input value for which to avoid copying (usually done for performance reasons).